# how to check if my ethernet interface is working properly or if it has a loose contact

Tags: debian, ethernet

I've used the ethernet interface rarely in the past on my debian 10. Last week I've updated my debian to debian 11. During the installation it failed to connect via ethernet. I've tried 3 different cable some of them are in daily use for my tv. So a faulty cable can be ruled out. It was quite a challenge to get through the installation as I need some non-open firmwire for my wlan interface.

So now I would like to figure out if it is a setup issue or my hardware (ethernet) is broken. I'm not at all a specialist in interfaces / hardware related stuff. So would be great if someone could tell me what's the most likely case.

Running a simple

```
sudo lshw -class network -short
H/W path               Device     Class          Description
============================================================
/0/100/1c.6/0          wlp3s0     network        Wireless 8265 / 8275
/0/100/1f.6            enp0s31f6  network        Ethernet Connection (4) I219-V
```

looks to me that the interface is wokring correctly, no? Does this mean the hardware has most likely a loose contact / is broken?

```
ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp0s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 8c:16:45:32:c8:b8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:21:6b:ff:ac:d5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

**Edit**

```
/usr/sbin/ethtool enp0s31f6
Settings for enp0s31f6:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Full
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Full
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: Unknown!
    Duplex: Unknown! (255)
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 2
    Transceiver: internal
    MDI-X: Unknown (auto)
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
    Link detected: no
```

**Edit 2**

After sample setting

```
sudo /usr/sbin/ethtool -s enp0s31f6 speed 100 duplex full
[sudo] password for nicolas: 
(srv) nicolas@debian:~/phd/src$ sudo /usr/sbin/ethtool enp0s31f6
Settings for enp0s31f6:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Full
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  100baseT/Full
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: Unknown!
    Duplex: Unknown! (255)
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 2
    Transceiver: internal
    MDI-X: Unknown (auto)
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
    Link detected: no
```

Comment: What is the result of `ethtool enp0s31f6`?

Comment: @RomeoNinov see my edit

Comment: try sample settings `ethtool -s enp0s31f6 speed 100 duplex full` and check what is the situation

Comment: @RomeoNinov it seems nothing has changed (see edit 2)...does this mean the hardware is broken? Cable was plugged in all the time, obviously

Comment: Yes, for me this looks like broken hardware. Also `Link detected: no` point me in this direction.

Comment: `NO CARRIER` indicates that there isn't a link. If the cables are alright, then it's probably the NIC. If it's the one that's built in, you can replace it with a PCI express NIC.

Comment: @RomeoNinov damn it! I thought so....happy to accept your comments as an answer.

Comment: @NasirRiley not an hardware expert but since this is for a laptop, it seems not that easy, no? i'm thinking to buy a UBS-C to lan adapter just as a backup solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments and based on the test (unsuccessful) to bring up interface with command:

```
ethtool -s enp0s31f6 speed 100 duplex full
```

I will say you have broken ethernet adapter. For me "`Link detected: no`" confirm this hypothesis. You can replace it with USB dongle (wireless or wired).

Also you can consider to send the machine in service center because usually these adapters are replaceable. Or do it by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

`NO CARRIER` indicates that a link is not being detected which indicates that the hardware for the interface has failed. That is why commands to bring it up are not working.

As this is a laptop, if it's still under warranty, then the vendor will usually repair or replace it.

You can also use a USB to Ethernet adapter instead. They can be acquired from Amazon for around $10 - $20.